# Average group by

Tags: google-data-studio

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Customer Id | Customer Name | Participants
customer #1 | C1 Name       | 10
customer #2 | C2 Name       | 20
customer #3 | C3 Name       | 30
customer #1 | C1 Name       | 100
```

I want to add a column that will calculate the change from averages of each customer.
i.e.

```
Customer Id | Customer Name | Participants | Performance
customer #1 | C1 Name       | 10           | -45
customer #2 | C2 Name       | 20           |
customer #3 | C3 Name       | 30           |
customer #1 | C1 Name       | 100          | 45
```

I need to create that `Performance` field that will group by the customer id, calculate the average and test how one-row performance compared to the average.

Is that possible?

Comment: [Add comparison metrics and running totals](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/9372465) can help you add a column with the performance and the average.